# How to extend/decorate third-party classes in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, interface, metaprogramming, aop, decorator

In Ruby all classes are forever open.  New behavior can be added to any class at just about any time.  Is there a way to do this in VB.NET?

For example, what if I want all DataRows in an existing app (a large one) to take on a new behavior.  I realize I could create a custom row class that inherits from DataRow, but inheritance is not what I'm after.  That would involved a lot of rework to make sure that at all places rows are instantiated, we are instantiating from our custom row class.

I had two rough ideas about how this might be done:

1. It occurred to me that aspects (AOP) could work here.  [Is there a way to layer behavior on top of existing methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395606/is-there-a-simple-means-of-adding-an-aspect-to-an-existing-vb-net-method)
2. Would it be possible to apply [a given Interface to existing classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368353/can-an-interface-be-retroactively-implemented-in-vb-net).

The primary goal here is to not have to do any large retrofit of existing code.  The system should practically remain oblivious to these layered-on behaviors/aspects.  It should involve a minimal change to the codebase.

Currently, we implement layered aspects using decorator classes.  The problem is, the system knows the difference between a native row and a row decorator object.  I want to be able to pass around something that the system thinks is a native row.  Again, the system needn't be mindful of the decorations applied to the row.  It should think it has a row, not some special decorator.

Specifically, I want to decorate the default set Item(colName) property of a row so that I can modify the incoming value.

Comment: One problem I have is that VB.NET has no native support of aspects.  I spotted a number of AOP frameworks.  IMO, adding aspects should be supported natively by the language.

Comment: Correct, you can only use AOP in .Net with a framework e.g. [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/features). Or Microsoft's Unity application block [eg](http://www.pnpguidance.net/post/UnityInterceptionExtensionExampleTransparentProxyPolicyInjectorHandlerAttributeICallHandler.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Much of what you are asking for is possible with Extension Methods.  See here for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx

Here's an example from that link which adds a `Print` method to all `String` objects:

```
Module StringExtensions
    <Extension()> 
    Public Sub Print(ByVal aString As String)
        Console.WriteLine(aString)
    End Sub
End Module
```

However, you can only use extension methods to add methods, not properties nor fields.  Also, you can only add a new method or overload.  You can't override an existing method with a new one.

Since what you are talking about, specifically, is the ability to override the indexer property on a class, extension methods won't help you in that case.  The only other option that I'm aware of would be to trick your projects into using your wrapper class instead of the real one.  You could create your own library that implements the same classes with the same names in the same namespace as whatever library you are trying to extend.  Your wrapper library would reference the real one and would inherit all the classes from the original one.  Then you could extend them all you want and your other projects could simply reference your library instead of the real one.  To do this, you would of course need to use lots of namespace aliasing and quite possibly assembly reference aliasing (which is not available in VB.NET, so you might have to write the library in C#, which supports it with the `extern` keyword).  But I suspect this may not be worth it for you.

Comment: I use extension methods extensively.  Unfortunately, they do not allow for any sort of decoration.  DataRow has a default property: Item.  I want to intercept messages to the Item setter.  For example, in Ruby, with one line of code, I could easily log the setting of row properties to debug something and, when I'm done, remove that line of code.  The key thing here is being able to easily add or remove the behavior with just a few lines of code, not a huge refactoring.